# Match simple regex pattern using JS (key: value)

Tags: javascript, regex, capture, key-value

I have a simple scenario where I want to match the follow and capture the value:

```
stuff_in_string,
env: 'local', // want to match this and capture the content in quotes
more_stuff_in_string
```

I have never written a regex pattern before so excuse my attempt, I am well aware it is totally wrong.

This is what I am trying to say:

- Match "env:"
- Followed by none or more spaces
- Followed by a single or double quote
- Capture all until..
- The next single or double quote

`/env:*?\s+('|")+(.*?)+('|")/g`

Thanks

PS here is a #failed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DfHge/

Note: this is the regex I ended up using (not the answer below as it was overkill for my needs): `/env:\s+(?:"|')(\w+)(?:"|')/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
/\benv: (["'])([^"']*)\1/g
```

where `\1` is a backreference to the first capturing group, thus your content is in the second. This is the simple way for simple cases.

Now, other cases like:

```
env: "abc\"def"
env: "abc\\"
env: "abc\\\def"
env: "abc'def"
```

You must use a more constraining pattern:

**first: avoid the different quotes problem:**

```
/\benv: (["'])((?:[^"']+|(?!\1)["'])*)\1/g
```

I put all the possible content in a non capturing group that i can repeat at will, and I use a negative lookahead `(?!\1)` to check if the allowed quote is not the same as the captured quote.

**second: the backslash problem:**

If a quote is escaped, it can't be the closing quote! Thus you must check if the quote is escaped or not and allow escaped quotes in the string.

I remove the backslashes from allowed content:

```
/\benv: (["'])((?:[^"'\\]+|(?!\1)["'])*)\1/g
```

I allow escaped characters:

```
/\benv: (["'])((?:[^"'\\]+|(?!\1)["']|\\[\s\S])*)\1/g
```

To allow a variable number of spaces before the quoted part, you can replace `:` by `:\s*`

```
/\benv:\s*(["'])((?:[^"'\\]+|(?!\1)["']|\\[\s\S])*)\1/g
```

You have now a working pattern.

**third: pattern optimization**

*a simple alternation:*

Using a capture group and a backreferences can be seducing to deal with the different type of quotes since it allow to write the pattern in a concise way. However, this way needs to create a capture group and to test a lookahead in this part `(?!\1)`["']`, so it is not so efficient. Writing a simple alternation increases the pattern length and needs to use two captures groups for the two cases but is more efficient:

```
/\benv:\s*(?:"((?:[^"\\]+|\\[\s\S])*)"|'((?:[^'\\]+|\\[\s\S])*)')/g
```

*(note: if you decided to do that you must check which one of the two capture groups is defined.)*

*unrolling the loop:*

To match the content inside quotes we use `(?:[^"\\]+|\\[\s\S])*` *(for double quotes here)* that works but can be improved to reduce the amount of steps needed. To do that we will unroll the loop that consists to avoid the alternation:

```
[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*
```

finally the whole pattern can be written like this:

```
/\benv:\s*(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*)"|'([^'\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^'\\]*)*)')/g
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know why it isn't working in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/KMBuq/

Comment: @infensus: because you have putted about 150 white spaces perhaps?

Comment: I put that as a test since the user could in theory have more than one space after the env: part. That is why I said "Followed by none or more spaces" or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 2):

`env *('|").*?\1` is what you're looking for

the `*` means none or more

`('|")` matches either a single or double quote, **and also saves it into a group for backreferencing**

`.*?` is a reluctant greedy match all

`\1` will reference the first group, which was either a single or double quote

Comment: Thanks, but do you know why it isn't working in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/2CBHt/

Answer (score 1):

```
regex=/env: ?['"]([^'"])+['"]/
answer=str.match(regex)[1]
```

even better:

```
regex=/env: ?(['"])([^\1]*)\1/
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know why it isn't working in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/sHe3T/1/

Comment: @infensus yes, replace the ? with a *, I misread your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/sHe3T/2/